# Move "preparation task" to a MainActivity before launching gui

Tags: java, android

I have a running Android java written application and I would like to improve it.

For know my mainactivity, called `DrugListActivty` extend `AppCompat`. In short it's a `recyclerView` with Room database management.

I would like to move some part of the code in a `MainActivity`, in charge of checking database or `onPause` for example.

For now (and it's not working) I made :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//some stuff
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrugListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

And `DrugListActivity` became

```
public class DrugListActivity extends MainActivity {

//etc
```

I have blink effect, `DrugListActivty` is launch again and again and again.

Is my idea bad (move to simply code)?
If is a good idea, there must be a right way to do it but I can't find any help.

So I'm asking the experts.

Thanks in advance for reading me, your advises and your time.

Comment: Extending `MainActivity` is odd. Why do you need to do this? In `DrugListActivity` are you overriding `onCreate()` and dies this call `super()`?

Comment: My idea was to have a more clean and small `DrugListActivity`.  

I schedule a notification in `onPause()` which come to often (each time `DrugListActivity` change for another activity) and move in a `MainActivity` above `DrugListActivity` sounds a good idea too.  

It was only a idea, with a separate branch that I can through.
Your right, I will override `onCreate()`.  

Thanks for your time and advises.